# How does serialize a list of objects in xml work?

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, serialization

I want to serialize my list of objects into a xml file with an path and deserialize it again.

I have a simple class of object with two strings:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    [Serializable]
    public class My_obj
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Score { get; set; }
    }
```

And i have a list of this objects:

```
    public List<My_obj> Score_Liste = new List<My_obj>()
    {
        new My_obj() { Name = "John Doe", Score = "one" },
        new My_obj() { Name = "Jane Doe", Score = "two" },
        new My_obj() { Name = "Joe Doe", Score = "three" },
        new My_obj() { Name = "Janna Doe", Score = "four" },
        new My_obj() { Name = "Jonathan Doe", Score = "five"}
    }; //List
 }
```

I tried something with Filestream and BinaryFormatter.
Can someone show me, what did i have to do.

Thank you.

Comment: Check out the [official MSDN example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/examples-of-xml-serialization).

Comment: I did. I watch so much youtube tutorials, read so much about the stuff, but i think everytime i swap to another side, the hole serialize process have changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example using the `XmlSerializer` in conjuction with `File.Open`

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;

var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<My_obj>));
```

Serialization:

```
using (var stream = File.OpenWrite(xmlFilePath))
{
    serializer.Serialize(stream, Score_Liste);
}
```

Deserialization:

```
using (var stream = File.OpenRead(xmlFilePath))
{
    var list = (List<My_obj>)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
}
```